# Difficulty Retracting or Excluding a Fact from Knowledge Base in SWI Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm new to Prolog, so any guidance would be welcome. I'm wondering about how to temporarily retract or exclude a specific fact with a certain property from the knowledge base, during execution.

My knowledge base consists of facts like the following: flight(city1, city2, airline, distance, time, cost), e.g.

```
flight(hongkong,london,ba,7500,700,1000).
flight(amsterdam,dublin,ryanair,1000,90,60).
flight(newyork,moscow,aerflot,9000,720,1000).
flight(hongkong,moscow,aerflot,5500,420,500).
flight(chicago,newyork,aa,3000,240,430).
```

I'm trying to create a list of lists which detail the different routes from one city to another, e.g. hongkong to newyork direct or hongkong - london - newyork. I have written the following code, which works, but I want to augment it to exclude certain airlines. This is the troubling bit. How can I exclude certain flights, depending on the airline?

This is the code which works:

```
trip(X, Y, T) :- connect(X, Y, [X], T).
connect(X, Y, V, [X, Y]) :- flight(X,Y,_,_,_,_), not(member(Y, V)).
connect(X, Y, V, [X|T]) :- flight(X,Z,_,_,_,_), not(member(Z, V)), connect(Z, Y, [Z|V], T).
```

I'd like to now exclude certain flights based on airline. This is what I've written, but it doesn't work. Perhaps an issue with retractall/1?

```
trip2(X, Y, A, T) :- connect2(X, Y, A, [X], T).
connect2(X, Y, A, V, [X, Y]) :- flight(X,Y,_,_,_,_), not(member(Y, V)), retractall(flight(_,_,A,_,_,_)).
connect2(X, Y, A, V, [X|T]) :- flight(X,Z,_,_,_,_), not(member(Z, V)), connect2(Z, Y, A, [Z|V], T), retractall(flight(_,_,A,_,_,_)).


all_trip_noairline(X,Y,A,T) :- findall(P, trip2(X, Y, A, P), T).
```

Comment: Hint: Change `flight(X,Y,_,_,_,_)` to e.g. `flight(X,Y,Airline,_,_,_)`, and then *compare* `Airline` to the one you want to exclude (using e.g. `dif`). Don't need `retractall`.